# ASP.Net MVC C# - Incorrect Html Display when visiting a page multiple times caused by CSS

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have created a basic ASP.NET MVC project.  I have an index view with a form and a simple label and text box and a submit button (see code below).  With the header on the page from the project I can move between multiple pages (about or contacts or home) this is a default project created in VS2012.

When I return to the index page I get what you see in this image:

[image: Incorrect View]

When it should look like this:

[image: What I expect to see]

Which is also what I see the first time I visit the page.

What am I doing wrong?

The view looks like this:

```
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Details","Citizen"))
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ID)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ID)
        <input type="submit"  value="Details" />
    }
</div>
```

EDIT:  I am using multiple CSS files, the standard that VS creates plus the `jquery.moblile-1.4.5` which I'm using for a collapsible list.  This looks to be causing it

Comment: what is html for wrong-looking page? how is it different from html of the correct page? "When I return to the index page" - by clicking a link and receiving the page from server or using browser Back button?

Comment: It is the same code.  When the project is created it has a _Layout.cshtml which has the header bar with just has actionlinks to the pages.  If I select about and then click home it runs the same view but when it displays it displays with an additional display around the text input area.  Each time I leave this page and return it adds an additional wrapper

Comment: I understood that it is the same code. I was asking about html that you can see by doing "View page source" in the browser.

Comment: oh, sorry the actual HTML has multiple of these <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">

Comment: ok, then we are onto something. You need to find how these div's are constructed (likely - client-side) - then you may understand why there are so many of them.

Comment: How do I do that?  (I did replace the @html with the code <div><input> code it generated and it still duplicated in the browser

Comment: PS using Chrome to view it

Comment: Interestingly I viewed it in internet explorer and it displayed almost correctly.  It flashes to the incorrect view but then corrects itself and displays correctly